# Prove 0=-0 (GH Hardy's, a Course in Pure Mathematics)

Tags: real-analysis

So I am working through Hardy's classic on my own and I need to get some feedback on how to proceed with the questions at the end of each section. Right now I am working on p. 18 example 4: Prove 0=-0.

Now Hardy gives the clue that all of the examples on p. 18 are consequences of the definitions that precede, which are thus:

" A section of the rational numbers, in which both classes exist and the lower class has no greatest member, is called a real number, or simply a number...(1)"

" It will be convenient to define at this stage the negative −α of a positive number α. If (a), (A) are the classes which constitute α, we can define another section of the rational numbers by putting all numbers −A in the lower class and all numbers −a in the upper...(2)"

Then to prove 0=-0 we would have to show, by the definitions above, that the upper and lower classes of 0,-0 are equal.  It is intuitive that this must be true, but I am new to proofs and not sure how to tackle it. Maybe by contradiction? Don't give it away point me on the right path. Thanks

Comment: Can you use the first quotation to give a section of 0? That is, can you give explicit classes (a) and (A) that constitute 0? And then can you use the second quotation to give a section (b) and (B) of -0?

Comment: Is this the idea?
Assume two numbers, alpha and beta, and their upper and lower classes: A, B, a, b respectively. If alpha is less than beta then we have:
All a's are b's but but not all A's are B's
In this case, if alpha is -0 and beta is 0 this implies there is a real number x where -0 < x < 0 which is absurd.
But I am not convinced this is a proof because it only tells me what I already know, that -0 = 0. But is it really a proof?

Comment: Hmm this seems better...This would require that there be a number in class A and b (where they overlap) that is greater than -0 and less than 0. But by definition (2) above we can define -0 with an upper class of -b and lower of -B (where B constitutes 0). Thus there is a number in class -b that is greater than -0, but also a number in class b (where it overlaps A) that is also greater than -0. This is a contradiction resulting in our assumption that 0 does not equal -0; hence our assumption is false